# WPF: ListBoxItem with scroll bar

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer, ui-virtualization

is it possible to have `ListBox`(which contains `ScrollViewer` by default) and `ListBoxItem` with `ScrollViewer`?
I want to achieve next view:
[image]

And this ListBox should also support virtualization. (I know how enable it, I just wondering will it work if I use 2 scroll viewers?)

**UPDATED:**
I need to use `ListBox.ItemTemplate`, since I'm binding `ItemsSource`.

Thanks for tips.

Comment: Scrollviewers are ugly. How about using `TextWrapping` instead?

Comment: `TextWrapping` is not appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy. *(I've given you three ways to do this, one must be right!)*

**Through Xaml:**

```
    <ListBox x:Name="ListBoxControl" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="320" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="520">
        <ListBoxItem Width="520">
            <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                <Label Content="My Name is KidCode. This is a reeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaly long comment."/>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
```

**From C#:**

```
namespace StackExchange
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var lbv = new ListBoxItemSV()
            {
                Height = 40,
                Width= 520,
                Background = Brushes.Blue
            };
            ListBoxControl.Items.Add(lbv);
        }

        public class ListBoxItemSV : ListBoxItem
        {
            ScrollViewer sv = new ScrollViewer()
            {
                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible,
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden
            };
            Label lbl = new Label()
            {
                Content = "A really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really long name."
            };

            public ListBoxItemSV()
            {
                sv.Content = lbl;
                this.Content = sv;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This results in the following: (I've added a short comment just so you can see the difference, you can probably make the scroll bar go all the way across, but this is just an example.)

[image: ListBoxItem with ScrollViewer]

**If your using Item Template:** *(I've never done this, so don't shoot me if its wrong! :) )*

**XAML:**

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBoxTwo">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Width="520">
                        <Label Content="{Binding}"/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
    List<string> Mylist = new List<string>();
    Mylist.Add("Short Name");
    Mylist.Add("Another Short Name");
    Mylist.Add("A massively, hugely, giganticly, monstorously large name. (Its even bigger than than you think...............) ");

    ListBoxTwo.ItemsSource = Mylist;
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Thanks, but I need to use `ListBox.ItemTemplate` since i'm binding items to `ListBox`

Comment: Always helps to include those sorts of details in the question.

Comment: @AnnaOsiatnik - Edited my answer. All three work, I believe the last one is what you want?